# Converting SQL geometry data queries into R spatial dataframes

Tags: r, sql-server-spatial

I'm interested in querying data with a geometry field from SQL server and using it in R as a spatialPolygonsDataFrame.

I've seen plenty of examples of using rgdal to import a shapefile, but shapefiles are far from the ideal storage medium for a map layer.

Can anyone point me to the correct syntax?

Does the geometry data have to be converted on it's way out of sql server in order for R to recognize it? to WKT or WKB for example?

In the end, I want a live connection to this data so that my maps are pulled directly from SQL and not from an exported shapefile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rgdal` package can use any data format supported by the underlying OGR and GDAL libraries. You can see which drivers you have for vector data with:

```
 ogrDrivers()
```

In my case I can see:

```
           name                             long_name write  copy isVector
40 MSSQLSpatial Microsoft SQL Server Spatial Database  TRUE FALSE     TRUE
```

amongst them, which means I can probably read and write directly from an MS SQL Server Spatial Database.

To do that, you need the OGR `dsn` for your database. This is a string of the form `"MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=geodb;trusted_connection=yes"` - where `MSSQLSERVER2008` is an ODBC connection identifier, which you create with the Windows ODBC tool - this is where the host and database names are defined.

Examples here: http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/rgdal-and-MSSQL-Server-geometries-td7583193.html There seems to be some possible complications with how the database stores geometry, but I don't have a server to test on....

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks so much, got it to work based on your help and the links you posted!!!

Comment: Instead of `.\MSSQLSERVER2008` I could use the server name. So I do not need to define DSN.

Comment: It works on Windows. However, I can not make to work on Linux.